# NLTK: How to access the chunked string

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, text-chunking

I am using NLTK chunking and i want to capture the string that was matched for my rule. For example

Here is my input

`The stocks show 67% rise, last year it was 12% fall`

i want to capture

`67% rise` and `12% fall`

POS Tagging the above sentence shows

```
('The', 'DT'), ('stocks', 'NNS'), ('show', 'VBP'), ('67', 'CD'), ('%', 'NN'), ('rise', 'NN'), (',', ','), ('last', 'JJ'), ('year', 'NN'), ('it', 'PRP'), ('was', 'VBD'), ('12', 'CD'), ('%', 'NN'), ('fall', 'NN')
```

Now, i came up with a simple rule

`Stat: {<CD><NN>(<NN>+|<VBN>|JJ)?}`

which works well and captures

```
('67', 'CD'), ('%', 'NN'), ('rise', 'NN')

('12', 'CD'), ('%', 'NN'), ('fall', 'NN')
```

now, i want to extract the exact strings that were captured. So, i want

`67% rise` and `12% fall`

i tried

```
current=[]
for word,tag in subtree.leaves():
    current.append(word)
print ' '.join(current)
```

but i get

`67 % rise` and `12 % fall`

notice the space between `%` and the numbers. This is logically correct but not the desired output. I want the exact string as i want to know the starting and ending indices of the captured strings.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Is the % _always_ joined to the number, i.e. do you always have `67%` as opposed to `67 %`?

Comment: yes, absolutely

Comment: The tokenizer doesn't keep track of the origin of tokens in the string, so any solution is going to be a  bit of a hack. I would certainly solve the problem at that level (match plain tokens to the raw string), then identify the chunks you are after on the basis of token index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Horribly hacky) 
For your example strings and tags:

```
s = ('The', 'DT'), ('stocks', 'NNS'), ('show', 'VBP'), ('67', 'CD'), ('%', 'NN'), ('rise', 'NN'), (',', ','), ('last', 'JJ'), ('year', 'NN'), ('it', 'PRP'), ('was', 'VBD'), ('12', 'CD'), ('%', 'NN'), ('fall', 'NN')
a = (('67', 'CD'), ('%', 'NN'), ('rise', 'NN'))
c = 'The stocks show 67% rise, last year it was 12% fall'
```

Edit: As a list comprehension:

```
>>>c[min((c.index(i[0]) for i in a)):max((c.index(i[0]) for i in a)) + [len(i[0]) for i in a][-1]]
>>>'67% rise'
```

Find the position that each word occurs within your input sentence. Record the length of each word.

Check what position your desired part of speech tags have within your sample sentence.
(Edit: Removed if as was unnecessary)

```
position=[]
lengths=[]

for wordtag in a:
    print wordtag,c.index(i[0]),wordtag[0],len(wordtag[0])
    position.append(c.index(wordtag[0]))
    lengths.append(len(wordtag[0]))

> ('67', 'CD') 16 67 2
> ('%', 'NN') 18 % 1
> ('rise', 'NN') 20 rise 4

print position
print lengths

> [16, 18, 20]
> [2, 1, 4]
```

Slice your input sentence according to the minimum and maximum position of your desired tags. You add a `lengths[-1]` to add the length of the word `rise`.

```
valid = c[min(position):max(position) + lengths[-1]]
print valid

> [16, 18, 20]
> [2, 1, 4]

> 67% rise
```

You can then generalise this for any list of sentences and part of speech tags.